# how to implement is_pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement is_pointer. I want something like this:

```
template <typename T >
bool is_pointer( T t )
{
   // implementation
} // return true or false

int a;
char *c;
SomeClass sc;
someAnotherClass *sac;

is_pointer( a ); // return false

is_pointer( c ); // return true

is_pointer( sc ); // return false

is_pointer( sac ); // return true
```

How can I implement it?
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type
{
    enum { value = false };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type<T*>
{
    enum { value = true };
};

template <typename T>
bool is_pointer(const T&)
{
    return is_pointer_type<T>::value;
}
```

Johannes noted:

> This is actually missing specializations for T *const, T *volatile and T * const volatile i think.

Solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_const
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_const<const T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_volatile
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_volatile<volatile T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_cv : remove_const<typename remove_volatile<T>::type> {};

template <typename T>
struct is_unqualified_pointer
{
    enum { value = false };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_unqualified_pointer<T*>
{
    enum { value = true };
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_type : is_unqualified_pointer<typename remove_cv<T>::type> {};

template <typename T>
bool is_pointer(const T&)
{
    return is_pointer_type<T>::value;
}
```

...but of course this is just reinventing the `std::type_traits` wheel, more or less :)

Comment: Is there a reason to use this solution over the one given by Thomas?

Comment: Yes of course:) I meant Thomas's answer but with `const T&` as parameter.

Comment: @Job If Davit ever needs to know whether a *type* is a pointer (as opposed to an *expression*), he can use `is_pointer_type`. One stone, two birds :)

Comment: This is actually missing specializations for `T *const`, `T *volatile` and `T * const volatile` i think. For this problem, you can call the trait with `is_pointer_type<T const volatile>::value` to work it around, but i suspect it would be nicer to put the burden of work into the trait :)

Comment: Why are using a enum?

Answer (score 12):

[From Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404270).

```
template <typename T> 
struct is_pointer 
{ static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T> 
struct is_pointer<T*> 
{ static const bool value = true; };
```

You can't do *exactly* what you want to do. You'll have to use this like:

```
is_pointer<int*>::value
```

It's not possible to determine this at run time.

Comment: Well, actually if you can have it at compilation, then you can have it at runtime. The reverse is usually more difficult. Anyway that's the solution I would be aiming for... or just using the Boost Type Traits library.

Comment: Peter this look good, but please look my example, I want to pass a variable like this: int ival; is_pointer( ival ); instead of is_pointer<int * > or is_pointer(int)

Comment: Every resource gives this implementation but I don't get why the partial specialization is chosen for `int *` or other pointer types, rather than first primary template? What is the mechanism behind? Is there a type deduction thing going on? I thought that was only possible for function templates.

Answer (score 9):

```
template <typename T>
bool is_pointer(T const &t) // edited: was "T t"; see the comments
{
   return false;
}

template <typename T>
bool is_pointer(T *t)
{
   return true;
}
```

You might not believe it, but it works. The reason is that the most specific template implementation will be chosen, which is the one which takes the pointer type.

Comment: True, it's not the best solution. That's why I upvoted Peter Alexander and you after posting this :)

Comment: +1 because this is exactly what the OP wanted. The prototype of the first function should be `bool is_pointer(T&)` for the reason FredOverflow has given in his comment.

Comment: @Job `T&` only binds to lvalues, I suggest `const T&` instead.

Comment: This solution is clearer to a beginner than the up-voted one; I think you should edit the 'const &' in as this is a commonly asked question.

Comment: Done. The `const &` won't have any unexpected side effects, I assume? How can we be sure that this is the case?

Comment: @GiuseppePes That comment no longer applies. In my original version, the first function accepted `T t` instead of `T const &t`, which obviously needs `T` to be copyable.

Comment: Why this is less preferred  way to implement is_pointer, against the answer given by fredoverflow??

Answer (score -2):

You can use "typeid" operator defined in typeinfo.h for this. 
check this link  : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid

The typeid operator will give an object of std::type_info class, which has a name() function returning char *. Once you get the type in string form, you can identify the pointer easily.

Hope it helps.

Romil.

Comment: -1, doesn't work. The set of std::type_info::name's for pointers may intersect the set of std::type_info::name's for non-pointers. In particular, all names can legally be `""`.

Comment: This. The string returned by .name is entirely implementation defined.