# How to delete a pointer if it is a template value?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a template class (`Node` is an inner class within a BST). It's now time to free up the memory; Given that either the key or the value (or both) may be pointers, I must figure out how to free them if they are.

See an example:

```
~Node( void )
{
    if ( is_pointer< TValue >( Value ) )
    {
         delete Value;
         Value = NULL;
    }

    if ( is_pointer< TComparable >( Key ) )
    {
         delete Key;
         Key= NULL;
    }
}
```

The implementation behind the `is_pointer< T >` function works (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177686/how-to-implement-is-pointer)), however as soon as I press delete on either Key or Value, I get the following:

```
Error   13  error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'esc::Shader' to 'void *'   c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\searchtree.hpp   131
Error   14  error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'esc::ShaderComparable' to 'void *' c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\searchtree.hpp   137
Error   12  error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   c:\programming\c++\git\escalator\engine\engine\searchtree.hpp   130
```

I've tried `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, etc, but neither of these appear to work.

What's a good solution?

Comment: Side note: trying to assign null to value and **then** delete makes no sense. `delete Value;Value = NULL;` would look better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
I must figure out how to free them if they are.
```

Don't. Really- don't. That's the *user's* problem- and he can supply a smart pointer if he wants this behaviour. After all, what if I want to map non-owning pointers? Or need a custom deleter?

Also, your code does not work because you compile the dead code `if` branches anyway, because you did not use a specialization.

Comment: I don't think this will work. A user should be able to delete a Node from a BST. So if it's something like: `BST->eraseNode(specific_key)`, then it would look weird if the user would have to `find()` the node first, then knowing the data type for `Value` he/she would do the `~Value` and memory deallocation and only after that the Node could be destroyed. Both distinguishing scalar pointers from non scalar data types and implementing custom deleters is extremely easy, users should not suffer from such an inconvinience, I think.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are storing copies of elements of type T instead of pointers as commonly done. If your declaration is `T Value;` than your Node class is normally not responsible for deleting Value object.

Comment: What is it that deletes it? Is there such a thing as automatic memory management in this case?

Comment: The question is who is **responsible** for the object. Maybe your expected usage pattern is that your Node class is always responsible for object (unlikely). Try to use your own class and see what your expectations are. There is a good chance that you'll find that `Node<char*>` does not mean Node needs to delete anything pointed by the value (i.e. you may have on large string with nodes pointing into random positions in it). You may want to explicitly specify ownership, but likely you will need `T* Value` in your Node class...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what kind of software you're working on here. Unless it's some quick test and you're not going to reuse the code, then yes, don't bother distinguishing pointers from objects or arrays. But if you're writing library code and you think your component will be reused by other people, then you should take care about cleaning after yourself. STL vector has been doing this successfully since the dawn of times. Last I saw the code they've been calling a Destroy function for (First,Last) elements of the vector with an value tag passed into the function as the third argument. And if elements are just plane scalar pointers (meaning int* for instance), then destructors need not be called. Obviously the real data has been allocated by the user and only addressed of the data has been stored in a vector, so it should not be deallocated. But if it's objects that are stored in the vector (objects of a user-defined class for instance, class A, lets say), then destructors need to be called for each element in the vector ~A() and after all of them ran to the end, the contiguous memory chunk that used to store the elements should be deallocated through the use of vectors allocator. For more information you can easily open vectors implementation, it's all in the header file, look at ~vector() implementation and let that guide you.