# How to ignore return types while using SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, sfinae

I have this piece of code:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
struct is_dereferenceable_exact
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef struct { char dummy[2]; } no;

    template <typename U, R (U::*)() const>
    struct SFINAE;

    template <typename U>
    static yes  test(SFINAE<U, &U::operator*>*);

    template <typename U>
    static no   test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

This struct is used for checking that given type is dereferencable, and result of dereferencing has type `R`. I used good old approach with ellipsis and `sizeof` instead of void_t or [detect idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) knowingly — I want to use only C++-03-features (if possible).

But I just cannot write analogous struct which determines *only* existence of `T::operator*` ignoring its type. Can you help me?

**UPD** I can generalize my question: if I can write some trait using return types, how I can eliminate them like in above primer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a type is dereferenceable in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834168/how-to-determine-if-a-type-is-dereferenceable-in-c03)

Comment: @ChrisBeck I don't think OP is asking on how to write an `is_dereferenceable`  trait but on how to dereference a member function without explicitly passing result type.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could also make use of sizeof operator trick:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_dereferenceable_exact
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef struct { char dummy[2]; } no;

    template <int>
    struct SFINAE;

    template <typename U>
    static yes  test(SFINAE<sizeof(&U::operator*)>*);

    template <typename U>
    static no   test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

struct A {
    int operator*() { return 0; }
};

struct B { };

int main() {
    std::cout << is_dereferenceable_exact<A>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_dereferenceable_exact<B>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3mp9pGpG89oJILOq)

Comment: Greate thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work on VS 2013 (error C2070: 'overloaded-function': illegal sizeof operand)

Comment: Another trouble came if class has both versions of `operator*`, const and non-const. As far as I understand, we cannot select overloading versions of `operator*` and template substitution falls back to `test(...)` specialization due to ambiguity (just add `int operator* () const` to `A` for testing)

Comment: @Quentin, as I understand, expression SFINAE doesn't support in VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I have no idea what I just did to conclude that it worked... You're right, and it *doesn't* work in VS2015 either. My bad.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: I think W.F.'s answer is correct under C++0x, but if what you really care about is VS 2013 you might want to tag the question like that

Comment: @ChrisBeck, I suppose that is a common trouble of old compilers, not only msvc